# Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

```
import urllib.request
import json

def printResults(data):
    
    theJSON = json.loads(data)
    
    if "title" in theJSON["metadata"]:
        print(theJSON["metadata"]["title"])
    
    count = theJSON["metadata"]["count"]
    print(str(count) + "events recorded") 
    
    

def main():
    
    UrlData = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php"
    # open url and read data
    webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(UrlData)
    print("result code: " + str(webUrl.getcode()))
    if(webUrl.getcode() == 200):
        data = webUrl.read()
        printResults(data)
    else:
        print("Received error, cannot parse results")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am receiving the error above in the title. I seem to have no idea why I am keep getting this error despite doing everything in the lecture right.

Comment: the url `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php` does not produce JSON. It's the url of the API docs. Example of API endpoint would be `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson`

Comment: point the url to  `https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_hour.geojson` and you will get a json

Comment: Problem is not resolved, I am getting the code 200 which means the I am able to link with the url but something is wrong with the theJSON = json.loads(data) line

Comment: you are getting 200. That doesn't mean it return JSON. Open your url in the browser!

Comment: If the problem is with parsing the data as json, can you print out the contents of `data`, and maybe show us an example here?

Comment: Your code worked for me with the URL https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson. It output "13519events recorded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works (your code does not work since the url you use does NOT point to a json doc)

```
import requests
import pprint

r = requests.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_day.geojson')
if r.status_code == 200:
    pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

output

```
{'features': [],
 'metadata': {'api': '1.10.3',
              'count': 0,
              'generated': 1631451490000,
              'status': 200,
              'title': 'USGS Significant Earthquakes, Past Day',
              'url': 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_day.geojson'},
 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

Comment: Same error even after using the link you have provided

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).